# Django: How to pre-populate a form when using non-model data?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In my case, the Django app is saving and getting user data to/from an external service via an API. I get an object with a number of user attributes, e.g. name, address, etc.

For updating of such information I'm using Django's native forms, with the shorthand template format, say: `{{ edit_account_form.as_p }}`

When I display the form to edit the information, I'd like to pre-populate it with the data from the user object. I know that I can pass the object into the template and render those values into the val and placeholder of each input field, however that would requite that I completely recreate the form input by input, which I'd prefer not to.

Possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [initial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) to declare the initial value of form fields at runtime. For example, you might want to fill in a username field with the username of the current session.

```
f = ContactForm(initial={'subject': 'Hi there!'})
```