# Django: How to pre-populate FormView with dynamic (non-model) data?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a FormView view, with some additional GET context supplied using get_context_data():

```
class SignUpView(FormView):
    template_name = 'pages_fixed/accounts/signup.html'
    form_class = SignUpForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SignUpView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context = {
            'plans':    common.plans,
            'pricing':  common.pricing,
        }
        return context
```

This works fine. However, I also have some values in session (not from any bound model) which I would like to pre-populate into the form. These vary depending on user's actions on previous page(s). I know (from my other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319651/django-how-to-pre-populate-a-form-when-using-non-model-data)) that I can pass the form into the context (with `initial=`) but is it possible in a FormView situation per above?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can override the FormView class's 'get_initial' method. See [here](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.6/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/) for more info,

e.g.

```
def get_initial(self):
    """
    Returns the initial data to use for forms on this view.
    """
    initial = super().get_initial()

    initial['my_form_field1'] = self.request.something

    return initial
```

'get_initial' should return a dictionary where the keys are the names of the fields on the form and the values are the initial values to use when showing the form to the user.

Comment: Thanks! Certainly seems like it ought to work but nothing comes through -- form remains blank (I have the return indented). I double-checked the form field key and session value are both good. Anything I could be missing still?

Comment: @pete try first getting the initial data from super() than update the dictionary with the fields you want to update it with and their values and return that. That should work

Comment: and yes my 'return' wasn't properly indented. I updated the ans again.

Comment: Doesn't like the return. Either getting `global name 'intitial' is not defined` or `'SignUpView' object has no attribute 'intitial'` (when I try: return self.initial)

Comment: Check your spelling of `initial`.

Comment: Ouch. Not usually this careless, really! (It's the deadlines ;)

Comment: If I have no name for my Form, it's a class view like `class ContactsViewInvite(generic.FormView):` and I just do `form_class = InviteFriendForm` how should it be written?

Comment: Excuse me for not getting this. I have the same situation pretty much but I also want to send a variable in the get_form_kwargs. If the GET request data is retrieved in the get_context_data mehod, do I just pass all the variables I need in the context dict and then call the method from get_initial() and get_form_kwargs()?

Comment: I used `self.request.GET` to get access to GET variables