# Django: Dynamic initial values for Form fail

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm using Django `django.forms.Form` and `django.views.generic.edit.FormView` to render a HTML template.

I would to add a default value for some of the fields in my form but it encounters a problem:

[image: Error:]

Here is my code:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class SignForm(forms.Form):
    greeting_message = forms.CharField(
        label='Greeting message', 
        widget=forms.Textarea, 
        required=True, 
        max_length=100,
    )
    book_name = forms.CharField(
        label='Guestbook name', 
        max_length=10, 
        required=True,
    ) 

class SignView(FormView):
    """Assign initial value for field 'book_name'."""

    form_class = SignForm(
        initial={
            'book_name': 'aaaa'
        }
    )

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `form_class = SignForm(...)` is initializing the form, it should simply be defining which form to use. Try changing it to `form_class = SignForm`, as far as setting the initial values, look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083218/django-how-to-pre-populate-formview-with-dynamic-non-model-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the comment above says, you must assign `form_class` just to the class. By doing what you have with the parenthesis and arguments, you are instantiating an object, which is why you have an exception.

Instead, to set initial data, define the `get_initial` function, like so:

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial = super(SignView, self).get_initial()
    initial['book_name'] = 'aaaa'
    return initial
```

[Docs are available here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_initial).

Answer (score 2):

You are attributing an instance to `form_class` instead of a form class like the name of the attribute implies. `SignForm` is the class, `SignForm(*args)` is an instance.

You should override the `get_initial()` method in the view:

```
def get_initial():
    return {'book_name': 'aaaa'}
```