# FormView - Specify which fields are sent in the POST

Tags: django, django-forms

Given a FormView associated to a Form, once the form is submitted some fields are sent to the FormView (those the user has filled).

Question: How can I send to the FormView other fields even if the user didn't fill them (because the fields were already prepopulated)? I need more data than the user provides in order to be used in *form_valid*

Comment: What do you mean by *send[ing fields] to the FormView*? If I understand what you want to do correctly, you can use `get_initial` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_initial) function of the `FormView` class to pre-populate your form. If you don't want those fields to be displayed to the user, hide them in you `Form` definition. Here is example usage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083218/django-how-to-pre-populate-formview-with-dynamic-non-model-data

Comment: @Siegmeyer I mean... I have a prepopulated form, users fill the fields they want and the data is sent to the FormView. Besides that, I want an specific field of the form is always sent with the rest of the data, no matter if a user has filled this specific field or not (has the default value from prepopulated step)

Comment: All fields from your `Form` definition are send in `request.POST` by default, no matter if they are hidden, pre-populated, filled by user or left untouched. After form validation you can all access them with `form.cleaned_data`.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is not sensitive you might want to add them to your form as hidden fields. In django you can achieve this with a [FormWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#hiddeninput). There are a few related questions here on SO:

- [Change a django form field to a hidden field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862250/change-a-django-form-field-to-a-hidden-field)
- [Django ModelForm to have a hidden input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795869/django-modelform-to-have-a-hidden-input)

Be aware that this just hides your data in the user interface, not in the browser - if you are in trouble if someone will change this data in an evil matter, you might consider writing the data in the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/).