# How can I achieve one single form, pre-populated with data from two different Profile instances?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a model, `Pair`, and another model `Profile`.

An instance of the model `Pair` will be made with a form that draws from two different `Profile` instances. So, how do I pre-populate a single form with bits of information from two Profiles?

Two models: `Profile` & `Pair`:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    favorites = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Pair(models.Model):
    requester = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    accepter = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    requester_favorite = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    accepter_favorite = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

The form so far:

```
class PairRequestForm(forms.Form):
    your_favorites = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    partners_favorites = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Code Explanation:  The way it works is, a user(`requester`) will request the initiation of a pair with the `PairRequestForm` to the potential `accepter`.
The form should be pre-populated with the "favorite" of each individual user.
I'm not sure how to wire up the views.py since I need to obtain two objects.

```
class PairRequestView(FormView):
    form_class = PairRequestForm
    template_name = 'profile/pair_request.html'
    success_url = "/"

    def is_valid(self, form):
        return
```

note: The pair form must be pre-populated with current information from the `Profile`. However, the form will not update any old information(will not `save()` any `Profile`s)--it will simply create a new `Pair` instance.

Comment: Why do you want a form if you're not updating/editing it?  From your request, it sounds like you can just do this by displaying the relevant info, based on two profile ids.

Comment: @Withnail It's not updating the Profiles. It is however creating a new Pair object.  Can you be a bit more specific re: "displaying the relevant info, based on two profile ids"?

Comment: If I understand right - you want to select an accepter from a list.  That proposer/accepter combination then becomes a Pair object, right?  Is the reason you're asking about Forms because you want to show the favourites combinations for each proposer/accepter pair, as you select them?

Comment: The accepter is not selected from any list--accepter is simply the user who happens to have the form on their page. So when the proposer submits a form on the accepter's page, they do become a pair(upon confirmation), and yes, I would like a form because the form must also show the favorites belonging to each user.

Comment: Ok, with you now! Let me just type it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the accepters page is visited at something like `/profiles/2`, you can capture the id of the accepter from the url, as you normally would.

Couple of things - you don't need to save the favourites into the Pair model, since for any use of the `Pair` model, you can just access them by doing

```
`p = Pair.objects.get(id=1) #or whatever query
 p.requester.favourites
 > Some of my favourites 
 p.accepter.favourites 
 > Some of your favourites.
```

If you, the proposer, are id=1, and visiting mine, the accepter's page (id=2), then you can populate the form - (I've done this in a very long manner for clarity)

```
accepterobj = Profile.objects.get(id=id_from_url_for_page)
proposerobj = Profile.objects.get(id=request.user.id) 

form = PairRequestForm(accepter=accepterobj, 
                       proposer=proposerobj, 
                       accepter_favourites=accepterobj.favourites,                                             
                       proposerobj_favourites=proposerobj.favourites)
```

in your CBV, [you can do the queries above by overriding the](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22083336/1293222) `get_initial` method on your `PairRequestView`.

```
def get_initial(self):
    """
    Returns the initial data to use for forms on this view.
    """
    initial = super(PairRequestView, self).get_initial()

    initial['proposer'] = self.request.user
    ...etc
    return initial
```