# Django CreateView's form not re-rendering as expected

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a form in which a certain field, `title`, is pre-populated when another field, `checkin_type`, is selected from a drop-down menu. I'm trying to follow the approach outlined in [Django: How to pre-populate FormView with dynamic (non-model) data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083218/django-how-to-pre-populate-formview-with-dynamic-non-model-data) and have put a 'proof-of-concept' project here: https://github.com/khpeek/django-dynamic-form.

In the view's template, I've made it such that when the `checkin_type` field has a `.change()`, an AJAX POST request is sent with the `id` of the selected check-in type:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');

        function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
            // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
            return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
        }
        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                }
            }
        });

        $(".auto-submit").change(function() {
            $.post({
                url: "{% url 'checkin-create' %}",
                data: {id: $(".auto-submit option:selected").val()}
            })
        });
    });
</script>


<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="{% if field.name == 'checkin_type' %}auto-submit{% endif %}">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Send message" />
</form>
```

In `views.py`, I've tried the following:

```
import logging
import sys

from django.views import generic
from .models import CheckIn, CheckInType

from django.http import HttpResponse


def get_stdout_logger(name, level):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(level)

    handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    handler.setLevel(level)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger


logger = get_stdout_logger(__name__, level=logging.DEBUG)


class CheckInCreate(generic.CreateView):
    model = CheckIn
    fields = '__all__'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.is_ajax():
            logger.debug(f"Received AJAX POST request with the following request.POST data: {request.POST}")
            self.checkin_type = CheckInType.objects.get(pk=request.POST['id'])
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        if hasattr(self, 'checkin_type'):
            initial.update(title=self.checkin_type.title)
        logger.debug(f"Getting initial: {initial}")
        return initial

    def form_valid(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.debug("The form is valid!")
        return super().form_valid(*args, **kwargs)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        logger.debug("The form is invalid!")
        if hasattr(self, 'checkin_type'):
            form['title'].initial = self.checkin_type.title
            logger.debug(f"The form's initial title is now {form['title'].initial}")
        return super().form_invalid(form)
```

Now, if I `python manage.py runserver`, navigate to `localhost:8000/checkins/new`, and select an option from the `checkin_type` drop-down menu, I see the expected logging results:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 01, 2018 - 21:02:14
Django version 2.0.1, using settings 'my_project.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:9000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
2018-03-01 21:02:18,595 - dashboard.views - DEBUG - Getting initial: {}
[01/Mar/2018 21:02:18] "GET /checkins/new HTTP/1.1" 200 2200
2018-03-01 21:02:26,015 - dashboard.views - DEBUG - Received AJAX POST request with the following request.POST data: <QueryDict: {'id': ['2']}>
2018-03-01 21:02:26,018 - dashboard.views - DEBUG - Getting initial: {'title': '2-week check-in'}
2018-03-01 21:02:26,018 - dashboard.views - DEBUG - The form is invalid!
2018-03-01 21:02:26,018 - dashboard.views - DEBUG - The form's initial title is now 2-week check-in
[01/Mar/2018 21:02:26] "POST /checkins/new HTTP/1.1" 200 2259
```

However, I'm not seeing the changes in the form! Should the call to `super().form_invalid(form)` not re-render the modified form?

Comment: You should see the request and response if you look at your browser's developer tools. When you use jQuery [`$.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), you should define a success handler to do something with the response. You haven't done this, so the ajax request will have no effect.

Comment: Note also that the form's initial data is only used when the form is blank. When you do a post request, the form is bound to the post data, so setting `form.inital` will have no effect.