# django set initial value in form

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

```
class UserEditFormView(FormView):
    template_name = "edit.html"
    form_class = UserEditForm
    
    def get_initial(self):
        return {'nickname': self.request.user.nickname}


class UserEditForm(forms.Form):
    nickname = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=120)


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>Nickname Edit</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form class="container" action="http://localhost:8000/profile/edit/" method="POST">

    <label for="nickname"> Nickname </label>
    <input id="nickname" type="text" name="nickname"/>

    <div>
        {{ form.nickname.errors }}
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Sign me up!</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to set initial value(placeholder) of the form but it's not working.
The input field on the page is empty.
I also post my html

Comment: initial are filled when you are rendering form in views.py. So when `GET` request is made then you will pass form with initial data there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: How to pre-populate FormView with dynamic (non-model) data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083218/django-how-to-pre-populate-formview-with-dynamic-non-model-data)

Comment: I saw all the similar questions and tried to fix it, but my code never work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `super().get_initial` first

```
class UserEditFormView(FormView):
    template_name = "edit.html"
    form_class = UserEditForm
    
    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()

        initial['nickname'] = self.request.user.nickname

        return initial
```

Comment: I tried it. But on the html, nickname's placeholder doesn't change

Comment: Can you provide how you are rendering your form ?

Comment: the code on the question is all I wrote.

Comment: show your `edit.html` file

Comment: I editted my question.